# Do I need the camera object and the light object?

Tags: camera, light

I want to create a 3d game with Unity so I started to learn Blender, but something that very annoy me in the 3d view window is that camera object and the light object. are they essential for modelling assets for my game or they are just for making movies?

so will it be ok to delete them?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Lights and cameras are only needed for rendering, if you are just modeling or texturing they are not needed for the moment, you can either hide or delete them for the time being . If you are modeling game assets then you are probably better off creating them in the game engine anyway.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos it is a problem to use the game engine Unity for modelling because you can't really design complex shapes there, you can use only some primitive shapes for my knowledge.

Comment: Oh sorry, I probably didn't explain myself correctly, I meant creating the lighting and cameras in engine, not the models. It is quite OK to model in Blender and export, that is the common workflow, but cameras and lights are always better to be created in engine.

Answer (score 2):

you can delete them now and readd any number of those later on if you'll need them.

also you can hide them - there is a list of scene objects in the upper right part of the UI, click on the eye icon next to those things to hide them.